# Targeting an android application to particular language(s)

Tags: android

I am developing an app that I would like to deploy to English speaking users first. I would like to target my app only to users who have set their device language as English (en_US, en_GB, etc). How do I achieve this?

Using Google developer console, I am able to target my app to specific countries and carriers but not based on language. For example, in countries like India and China, I want to target my app only to users who's device has English as its language. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

You can't. After all, the user is welcome to change their device's locale at any point in time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not want the user to change his/her locale for my app. I want the app to be visible (in app store) only to users with certail locale settings. I guess this is not possible ..

Comment: @user3268403: "I do not want the user to change his/her locale for my app" -- the user sets the locale for the *device*. Most devices will have more than just your app. "I want the app to be visible (in app store) only to users with certail locale settings" -- since locale settings can be changed at any time, the Play Store does not restrict visibility on that, any more than the Play Store lets you restrict distribution to devices which have a printer within 37cm, or to devices that are held at a 45-degree angle from the vertical axis, or to devices that are forever locked in a drawer.

Comment: I wouldn't compare locale to some of things you mentioned, but I understand your point now.

Comment: @user3268403: Sorry, I was short on sleep yesterday, and those came to mind. But basically, if its changeable by the user, the Play Store does not support filtering upon that. So while you can filter on whether the device has Bluetooth, you cannot filter on whether the device is paired with a hands-free unit. While you can filter on whether the device has WiFi, you cannot filter on whether the user *uses* WiFi. While you can filter on whether the device has NFC, you cannot filter on whether the user has set up "Tap & Pay". And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the user from installing your app, but you can check the device language in your first activity, and finish it if required.

Comment: So there is no way to make my app visible (in the app store) to users using a certain language? Checking in the first activity and quitting will lead to uninstalls and lower ratings ....